# Why am I receiving this error message "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sigma_opt' referenced before assignment"

Tags: function, python-3.x, error-handling, functional-programming

I have a dataset that follows a lognormal distribution. If I plot the y-values against the x-values on a semilog-x axis, the distribution will appear Gaussian. Similarly, if I sort the logarithm of every value in my dataset and plot them against a domain of log(x), the distribution will appear Gaussian (but nicer due to wider linear spacing of log(x) values on the domain). My code attempts to minimize chi square of the dataset in the three representations above by optimizing the parameters mu and sigma (since the average of the lognormal distribution does not equal the average of the normal distribution). My issue is not the chi square minimization (works for 2/3 of these representations), but rather the syntax in one specific part of my code.

To simplify the code, I use a function argument `pickdist` to denote which distribution is being dealt with. In the code below, `2` denotes the y vs semilog(x) representation, `3` denotes the y vs log(x) representation, `optpar2` and `optpar3` are parameters calculated previously from the code (not shown) and represent the optimized values of mu and sigma for the distributions.

```
def distribGS(pickdist, x):
    if pickdist == 2:
        mu_opt, sigma_opt = optpar2
    elif pickdist == 3:
        mu_opt, sigma_opt = optpar3
    cnorm = 1/ ( sigma_opt * (2 * pi)**(1/2) )
    return [(( cnorm * exp( (-1) * (x[index] - mu_opt)**2 / ( 2 * (sigma_opt **2) ) ) )) for index in range(len(x))]
```

The reason for this attempt at code is to plot this fit of data against the (normalized) histogram of the actual data. However, I am getting an error when I run the code that reads:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sigma_opt' referenced before assignment
```

I find this weird because `sigma_opt` is only defined inside of a few functions but is not defined globally. *I've read other posts on SO that deal with this error message, but none apply to my case.* Why am I receiving this error message? (I would post the whole code but it's 350+ lines)

Comment: What'll happen when `pickdist` is neither 2 not 3?

Comment: I have yet to write a raise value error statement. I can do that after debugging the main parts first.

Comment: I see you didn't get my point. When you pass something different that 2 or 3 to this function, you'll get an `UnboundLocalError`. `sigma_opt` is only assigned within if/elif, so it's **not assigned** when none of the conditions are met.

Comment: It should be assigned properly. I can look at it in an hour or so, and update accordingly.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I don't care that _It **should** be assigned properly_ - it's clear form the code that there are possible paths where **it is not assigned**. It's as simple as that - there's no subjectivity to it.

Comment: I thought I assigned it properly but I did not. You were correct, thanks. You posted your solution first. If you post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error because if you call 'distribGS' function with 'pickdist' attribute different than 2 or 3 'sigma_opt' variable becomes used without assignment first.

What you can do is assign 'sigma_opt' variable in the beginning of your function to some default value, or use 'else' statement to assign default value to it.
For example

```
def distribGS(pickdist, x):
    mu_opt, sigma_opt = 0
    if pickdist == 2:
        mu_opt, sigma_opt = optpar2
    elif pickdist == 3:
        mu_opt, sigma_opt = optpar3
    cnorm = 1/ ( sigma_opt * (2 * pi)**(1/2) )
    return [(( cnorm * exp( (-1) * (x[index] - mu_opt)**2 / ( 2 * (sigma_opt **2) ) ) )) for index in range(len(x))
```